# Traducción del Privilegio Comentar Dondesea

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, traducciones

Hoy he coneguido este privilegio y nada mas abrir la página he visto el titulo **Comentar dondesea**

Creo que este es el sitio correcto, para indicar de este fallo, ya que lo correcto sería  **Comentar donde sea**, en caso de estar equivocado, por favor indicarmelo y borraré el comentario.

Se puede ver en 
[Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > Comentar dondesea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: En realidad debería ser "Comentar en todos lados" :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que esta mal traducido

> "Comment Everywhere"

"dondesea" no tiene significado en español, pueden ser como opciones:

- Comentar donde sea
- Comentar en todos lados

Me quedaría con la segunda opción.

Comment: Yo estoy contigo, mejor la segunda

Comment: Creo que sí, que la mejor traducción sería **Comentar en todos lados**

Answer (score 4):

Lo he cambiado a "Comentar en todas partes", creo que suena un poco más formal que "en todos lados".